# Want to make Excel file heading bold

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I want to make the Excel file heading as bold.
In below code I clearly mentioned the headings that I want to make bold:

```
excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"trial.xlsx", data_only=True)
sheet = excel_document["Sheet1"]
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheets = wb.active
#Following are the headings, i want to make bold
sheets.cell(row=1, column=1).value="Device Type"
sheets.cell(row=1, column=2).value="Device ID"
sheets.cell(row=1, column=3).value="Status"
```

Comment: xlsx writer can do that for you: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_header_format.html#ex-pandas-header-format

Comment: Formtting is covered in the openpyxl doumentation. @fbence not for existing files it can't!

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font

bold_font = Font(bold=True)
```

For individual cells, you could do

```
sheets.cell(row=1,column=1).font = bold_font
```

Or, as in your case, if you want to set an entire row,

```
# ["1:1"] for the first row
for cell in sheets["1:1"]:
    cell.font = bold_font
```

See [the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) for more information on using styles.